# How to add text next to the quantity on the cart in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm not a developer, but i'm trying like heck.  I have two product tags. One product sold by "each", tag#1, the other product is sold by sq ft, tag#2.  I'm trying to display "each" or "sq ft" next to or under the quantity box on the cart page.  I've been able to add it next to product prices, but I can't for the life of me get this displayed next to quantity input only on the cart page.  Any help from one of you experts is greatly appreciated!

**This section works fine.**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'mto_text_after_price' );

 function mto_text_after_price($price){

if( !has_term( 'clearance', 'product_tag')) {
$text_to_add_after_price  = ' each '; //change text in bracket to your preferred text 
}

if( !has_term( 'cove-base', 'product_tag')) {
$text_to_add_after_price  = ' Sq Ft '; //change text in bracket to your preferred text 
}
      
return $price .   $text_to_add_after_price;
      
}
```

**This section does not on the cart page...and excuse my mess**

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_quantity_input_field', 'wc_text_after_quantity');

function wc_text_after_quantity() {
   //if ( is_cart() && is_product() && !has_term( 'clearance', 'product_tag' ) ) {
   // echo '<br>Each';
  // }
 if ( is_cart() && has_term( 'cove-base', 'product_tag' ) ) {
      echo '<br>Each';
 }
          elseif ( is_cart() && has_term( 'clearance', 'product_tag' ) ) {
    echo '<br>Sq Ft';
}
 

 // if( is_cart() && !has_term( 'clearance', 'product_tag')) {
//echo '<br>Each';
//}

//  if( is_cart() && !has_term( 'cove-base', 'product_tag')) {
//  echo '<br>Sq Ft';
//  }

 //foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){

 // For product Tags (term IDs, term slugs or term names)
 // if( !has_term('cove-base', 'product_tag', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
   // echo '<br>Sq Ft';
//}

//}

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

/* this may help you, not sure but you can figure out */
/* it may be relate to your stuff */

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'qty_front_add_cart' );
 
function qty_front_add_cart() {
 echo '<div class="qty">Sq Ft</div>'; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I will see how to incorporate this.